# AWS S3 TransferManager - thread named [java-sdk-progress-listener-callback-thread] but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST controller on my web app that upload photo onto S3. All seems working fine but when i shutdown the web server I get this in the log:

```
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [java-sdk-progress-listener-callback-thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and here is my REST Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> testupload(
        @RequestParam(required = true, name = "photo") MultipartFile uploadedfile)
        throws Exception {

    String filename = uploadedfile.getOriginalFilename();

    /* a local temporary file base on the upload filename */
    File tmpFile = LocalTempFile.getFile(filename);

    String s3RepoName = "myveryfirsttestingrepoanditsjustforme";

    TransferManager tx = new TransferManager();

    try {
        uploadedfile.transferTo(tmpFile);

        String s3Filename = filename;
        Upload upload = tx.upload(s3RepoName, s3Filename, tmpFile);

        upload.waitForCompletion();

        System.out.println("Transfer: " + upload.getDescription() + " ("
                + upload.getProgress().getBytesTransferred() + " bytes)");

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        /* do nothing */
    } catch (Exception e) {

        tx.shutdownNow();
        tmpFile.delete();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    // After the upload is complete, call shutdownNow to release the
    // resources.
    tx.shutdownNow();

    tmpFile.delete();

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("uploaded", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Do I need to worry about this error message? 
I'm using Tomcat8 + Java8 + SpringREST + AWS SDK (1.10.34). Any help would be greatly appreciated.